# How to setup zsh personal config (.dotfiles/zsh/zshrc) at every start on Raspberry Pi 400

Tags: raspberry-pi, zsh, raspbian, zshrc

I am training myself on Linux with a Raspberry Pi 400 (OS: Raspbian) and I would like to setup my personal config file for apps (notably the Terminal in `Zsh`). I am able to setup my config onto the terminal with the following:

```
$ cd .dotfiles
$ ./export.sh
$ cd zsh/
$ source ./zshrc
```

The problem comes when I quit the terminal or if I open a new terminal or if I reboot the computer, the config is not "saved".

I am not an expert, but for changing `bash` to `zsh` and maintaining it as default shell language, I did the following:

```
$ nano /etc/passwd
```

and changed the following line from :

```
pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
```

to:

```
pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/zsh
```

This move managed to get me `zsh` from start every time now. I am wondering if i can directly source my `.zshrc` with the same technique ... Or would you have any better idea?

I would like to avoid repeating the sourcing steps at every start in the terminal ...

Comment: This is not a programming question, and as such likely to get closed here on stackoverflow.  That said, zsh expects its main config file as `~/.zshrc` (note the leading dot).  For the future: this kind of question is better suited for SuperUser.com, I think.

Comment: Thank you mister Regner!